# how to send on previous page where a part of html was loaded

Tags: jquery

i m using Jquery ajax post method to edit a form on same page, but if there is some mistake then how do i send user back on that page where data were loaded.

now i describe u what i do?

i have a page `manageMovies.php` there are list of movie name, now when i click on a name of any movie,
then i load  `editMovie.php` on same page
now when i do some mistakes( i.e when validations fails) then i want to go back on same page
`manageMovies.php` loaded with `editunit.php` regarding that movie on the page.

here is my page structure

#### manageMovies.php

```
<div id="display"></div>
<div id="movieList">
  <table >
        <tr><td id="mov_10">Apharan</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="mov_11">Gangaajal</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="mov_12">Rajniti</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery('td').click(function () {
        jQuery('#movieList').hide(); // hide the  div 'movielist'
        jQuery.post('editMovie.php', {
            idForEdit: jQuery(this).attr('id')
        }, function (data) {
           jQuery("#display").html(data); //display the editMovie.php page on 'display' div
        });
    });
</script>
```

---

now when i do some mistakes on `editunit.php` and go further for post, then i need to go back on same page `(manageMovies.php)` where
`editMovie.php` is shown on `display` div and `movielist` div should be hidden

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) data.
For example when you click button "edit", you go to edit page.
Inside the page we have ID of record.
Now we can load [JSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) data of your object from your php script.
And "onPost" if you get error, you can just run reinit function and load again "clean" data for you model.